# Elastic search 2.4 upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Will Elastic Search 2.4 work on Lucene 4.10.3 or I need to upgrade to Lucene 5.5.2 as well?

Comment: Elasticsearch comes with the right librairies.
WDYM?

Comment: I mean for complete upgradation of elastic search from 1.4.3 to 2.4 i need to have to add all the jars that comes with elastic search 2.4 libraraies??

Comment: When using a transport client?

Comment: Or are you using elasticsearch embedded ?

Comment: We are using transport client

Comment: Yes. You need to add all the jars needed by elastic transport client artifact. If you are using a dependency manager (maven, gradle...) , it will do that automatically for you.

Comment: Yes you need to upgrade other jars which come along with ES distribution. If you use old lucene jars then some features might work but then for some features you would get exception. So its not a good idea to use old jars with new version of ES.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Nikhil Bhide, having different versions of dependent JAR-files can lead to unexpected behavior and instability in general. Good practice would be to update all of them to the version used to compile the ES JAR-file.

The ES 2.4.0 JAR-file uses the following packages of Lucene 5.5.2:

- lucene-core
- lucene-backward-codecs
- lucene-analyzers-common
- lucene-queries
- lucene-memory
- lucene-highlighter
- lucene-queryparser
- lucene-suggest
- lucene-join
- lucene-spatial

You can find a list of all compile dependencies for the ES 2.4.0 JAR-file here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0

If you want to use a different version, you can find similar pages here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch